# Which estates/factions supported the war in Livonia under Ivan IV

Tags: russia, 16th-century

The question of war with Livonia was divisive for the social estates in Russia. I am interested in which factions/estates supported or opposed the war.

I know Aleksey Adashev, who was a, okolnichy, a very similar rank to boyar and close advisor of Ivan IV opposed a continuation of the war in 1560. Prince Kurbsky opposed the continuation of the war by 1560 and Ivan Sheremetev together with Nikita Sheremetev did as well, both members of the wealthy Boyar Sheremetev family and on the Boyar council. A close associate of Adashev, Prince Dimitry Kurliatev was punished by Ivan IV in 1562 but I do not know if he was also opposed to the Livonian war. I read that there was a faction of princely-boyar opposition to "big war" with Livonia of which the Sheremetev's were part of, but I was not able to find more information regarding this faction. Was there such a princely-boyar opposition? Who else was part of it? The fact that during the Oprichnina Ivan only very selectively tried to repress the boyars and princes, suggests to me that princely-boyar opposition to the Livonian War was not a phenomenon encapsulating the entire estate, but only certain sections of it. An old Soviet book titled *History of the USSR in Three Parts Part I: From the Earliest Times to the Great October Socialist Revolution* states that the opposition mainly came from the old titled Moscow boyars who surrounded princes Shiusky. There is also the fact that the boyar representatives at the Zemsky Sobor of 1566 voiced their support for a continuation of the war in Livonia, although in *Ivan the Terrible: First Tsar of Russia* Isabel de Madariaga argues that the representation at the Zemsky Sobor did not represent the general attitudes of the estates, since social estates were not yet formed in Russian society.

The same caviat goes for the merchant representatives that were invited to the Zemsky Sobor of 1566. I am interested in whether the merchants generally had the same attitude to the war, or if there were specific factions of merchants with specific attitudes to the war.